# Is it possible to create a mixed Master-Detail and Tabbed bar application with Xcode?

Tags: xcode4.3

I'm trying to create a Master-Detail iPad application with a list of saved files in the Master view, and the main interface in the detail view.  There will be many different views in the detail, however, and I would like to be able to use a tab bar so users can quickly move between detail views.  Is it possible to create a tab bar to navigate just between the different detail views, and still keep the same master view?  I could just put in a "main menu" type view, which would have buttons to get to all the different main interfaces, but I'd like to avoid doing that if I can.

Thanks!
Mike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From everything I've seen, this type of layout isn't possible, and isn't really consistent with what a split view should be used for.  The more appropriate way to do this would be to use standard UIViews in a UITabBarController, then having the saved files as it's own view opened in a popover.